# Import one KMM module into another and expose it's classes to iOS

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm trying to bundle couple KMM modules into one and make them accessible in iOS.
I have **moduleA** and it imports **moduleB** like so:

```
val commonMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            api(project(mapOf("path" to ":moduleB")))
        }
    }
```

In android, if I import moduleA, I can also directly access classes from moduleB.
But on iOS, I can only see classes from moduleA. Is there a way to get moduleB classes visible in iOS as well without moving everything into moduleA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually configure the native framework to export the modules you want accessible to iOS:

```
    framework {
        ....
        transitiveExport = true
        export(project(":moduleB"))
    }
```

See also: https://akjaw.com/modularizing-a-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-project/